# Indexing a 2D vector is crashing my program

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

I'm taking input from a txt file and storing it in a 2D vector. That part works fine. My program seems to error out as soon as I try and access individual elements of the 2D vector. From what I've searched, I'm indexing the vector the correct way, so does anyone know why this would crash my code?

edit: I am accessing the vector correctly. getInput2D() is actually failing to append temp_vec to output_vector. What would be the correct syntax then be to dynamically create a 2D vector in this situation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector.>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<string>> output_vector{};

void getInput2D() { 
    
    ifstream file("C:\\Users\\ImTheUser\\Documents\\input.txt");
    string line;
    vector<string> temp_vec;
    
    if (file.is_open()) { 
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            if (line[0] != ' ') {
                temp_vec.push_back(line);
                temp_vec.clear();
            }

            else {
                output_vector.push_back(temp_vec);
                temp_vec.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

int main() {
    
    getInput2D();
    cout << output_vector[0][0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should check the size of `output_vector` and then check the size of its second subvector before accessing `[1][2]`. Depending on the file contents the vector may have less elements than you think

Comment: btw you never clear the `temp_vec` so in the end `output_vector` will contain the same `line`s several times

Comment: Program crashes when I access any index, updated the code to access [0][0] with same results

Comment: Do no lines start with a space? If so you will never add `temp_vec` to `output_vector`. With that said @largest_prime_is_463035818 has identified 2 potential problems in the code that you  probably should fix and retest.

Comment: After `output_vector.push_back(temp_vec);` you should do `temp_vec.clear();` and before or after `file.close();` you should do `output_vector.push_back(temp_vec);`. On that subject you don't really need `file.close();` at all. The destructor for ifstream will close the file for you.

Comment: Remove the `temp_vec.clear();` that is after `temp_vec.push_back(line);` this is wrong and will end up throwing away the line you read. Keep the the other `temp_vec.clear();` that is after `output_vector.push_back(temp_vec);`

Answer (score 2):

> I'm indexing the vector the correct way, so does anyone know why this would crash my code?

Assuming you are absolutely certain that `output_vector` has 1 or more elements and that its first element has 1 or more elements, this is the correct way to access them:

```
cout << output_vector[0][0] << endl;
```

However, as you are reading from an external ressource (a file), you cannot be absolutely certain that the vector has any elements at all and you should not rely on such assumptions. Instead use either a loop:

```
for (const auto& lines : output_vector) {
    for (const auto& line : lines) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

to print all elements that actually are in the vector. Or check its size before:

```
if (output_vector.size() > 0 && output_vector[0].size() > 0) {
     std::cout << output_vector[0][0];
} else {
     std::cout << "error. output_vector is empty\n";
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. I assumed that push_back() was actually appending temp_vec to output_vector, but after trying both approaches, I can definitively say that output_vector is empty after I run getInput2D(), so I am accessing the vector right, but I'm creating output_vector wrong.

Comment: @Schteve maybe I should have emphasized it more. The crucial point is: Even if you get your code to work and `cout << output_vector[0][0] << endl;` does what you expect, you should not assume that it does work for all input from the file. When reading from a file, consider that things go wrong, and recovering from an error is much easier when you consider that from the start, not only when the error already happened. Ie check the size of `output_vector` anyhow, even if you "know" that it is correctly populated from the file